# ASP.NET MVC 3 on IIS gives 403 after period of time, requires app pool restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, application-pool, http-status-code-403

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 site running on Windows 2003 / IIS 6. Everything works fine for awhile (days/weeks at a time), and then I start getting 403 errors. This happens if a user goes to the root of the domain, as well as going to any other full route. Restarting the app pool fixes the 403 and everything goes back to normal, but I am trying to figure out the root problem so it does not go down and require a manual app pool restart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the same symptoms - [Asp.Net-MVC application dying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824750/asp-net-mvc-application-dying)

I do experience the same issue with IIS6/MVC3. It seems to be somehow related to routing...

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue for my environment. The env is the following: Web proj (asp.net mvc app assembly) and Web.Controllers proj (class library). Routing initialization was made from Web.Controllers. I have figured out that when IIS shuts down an app and then starts in upon request then NOT all references are loaded for Web proj automatically. In particular, my Web.Controllers assembly was not loaded and thus routing was not re-configured upon app re-start. I replaced inderect Web->Web.Controllers dependency (IoC) with direct reference and that solved the issue.